# function gets function as an argument and throws 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python, numpy, arguments

I call a function with other function as an argument. The other function return numpy.ndarray.

The code:

```
class CLASS:
    def method1(self):
        size = 10
        return np.zeros([size,size])
    def method2(self, method):
        res = method()

a = CLASS ()
b = a.method2(a.method1())
```

The first function throws me
**TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable**

I want to run `method2()` in the cycle giving different functions as an argument.

**QUESTION**: Is it any way to run that in Python 3?

Comment: I have trouble understanding your question. Consider reformatting it with an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are passing the *result of calling* `method1` (which is in fact a `numpy.ndarray`) into `method2` rather than the method itself.

The call at the end should be `a.method2(a.method1)` without the parens.

Answer (score 0):

The `a.method1()` returns the result of `np.zeros(...)` which is a `numpy.ndarray`

So When you're trying to call `method()` in `method2()` it fails because that's not a function.

You probably want this instead:

```
import numpy as np

class CLASS:
    def method1(self):
        size = 10
        return np.zeros([size,size])
    def method2(self, glcm):
        pass

a = CLASS ()
b = a.method2(a.method1())
```